# AdSense не видит код

Tags: google-adsense

25.04. я отправил заявку на активизацию в программе AdSense, вставил **нужный код** между тегами `<head></head>`. Такеж было написано, что активизация занимает обычно 1-2 дня.
26.04. я получил письмо с напоминанием о том, что **код** (который я уже вставил) нужно вставить на сайт, в тоже самое место.
Что делать в таком случае? Все проверил, **нужный код** действительно между `<head></head>`.

Comment: Код покажите. Как вставляли-то?

Comment: Сайт - pirmaisdarbs.lv . Буду рад вашей помощи

Comment: В разделе head я вижу вот такой код:
    <script>
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
        google_ad_client: "ca-pub-1359768887425737",
        enable_page_level_ads: true
        });
    </script>
Но вот ниже на странице я что-то не нашёл кода, где вставляется непосредственно рекламный блок. Ткните меня пальцем. ))

Comment: Кстати, это же и  есть, по крайней мере, очень похоже на собственно рекламный блок. Только место ему не  в разделе head, а на странице в контенте, там. где вы отвели место этому рекламному блоку.

Answer (score 0):

У меня на сайте рекламный блок выставлен таким образом:

```
<div class="adv1">
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- Block_one -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
        style="display:block"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-7050009044715682"
        data-ad-slot="3712704651"
        data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание, этот блок находится на странице в body, а не в разделе head.

Comment: Вроде все верно сделал. На сайте ничего не изменилось, видимо надо ждать проверки. Спасибо тебе! Если вдруг что вспомнишь, скажи. https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/4/28/f2bd967b47e7c4049419dd251bff3895-full.png